# I want to hide a div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I created a div contaning a form and a button. I want to hide the entire div when the button is clicked.

```js
function myFunction() {
    let x = document.querySelector("div");
    if (x.style.display == "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<div onmouseover="firstPageDisplay();" id="firstPage">
    <div><img id="imgs"></div>
    <div class="center">
        <form class="center">Authentification<br>
            <p>Login</p> <input id="login" type="text"><br>
            <p>Password</p> <input id="password" type="password"><br><br>
            <button onclick="myFunction();" id="btnA">Se connecter</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what I tried to do, however when I click the button, the div disappears for a split second then reappears again. When I removed the button from the div it worked just fine. How can I make it disappear for good?

Comment: `document.querySelector("div")` is a _very_ broad query for a div, are you aware of that?

Comment: Assign the main container that you want to hide an id and select it by using document.getElementById("EnterId");

Comment: Instead of setting the style attribute (indirectly), define a CSS class and toggle it using `yourdiv.classList.toggle(...)`. Unless you're updating css variables, there's no good reason to directly manipulate the style object. Also, don't stick JS in HTML attributes, just keep your JS on the JS side so you can properly control what that button has to do.

Comment: If you have a `<form>`, the default action for a button is to submit, as default this is going to cause a page reload too. That's likely why it disappears then re-appears...

Answer (score 0):

you have `document.querySelecor('div')` which is selecting the first `<div>` in the whole document, probably not what you want.

the error is here

```js
function myFunction() {
    let x = document.querySelector("div");
    if (x.style.display == "none") { // error
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

you can only set a style, not get a style. Why? Because reasons nobody with common sense will understand. so instead you have to use `getComputedStyle(element).styleName`

```js
function myFunction() {
    let x = document.querySelector("div"); // if this is div you want
    if (getComputedStyle(x).display == "none") { // 
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

but as mentioned in a comment above, toggling a class and using event listeners are much better practice